Import CSV into Google Sheets using Apps Script - Timeout issues
I'm running into timeout errors with the script below which takes a csv file from an email and copies it into Google Sheets. I've tested importing the data into a separate workbook with no formulas tied to the data and it runs quickly, ~35k rows in under 30 seconds. So, I believe the issue is that all of the SUMIF formulas in my original workbook are causing it to continuously recalculate as it copies in new data. Others for similar issues have suggested using Advanced Sheets Service to fix this. Can someone help alter the code to use the spreadsheets.values.update method instead of setValues? Or is there a better route?
function importcsvsales () {

var threads = GmailApp.search("subject:Sales");
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a CSV file

attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
//attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

sh0.getRange("A1:L199999").clearContent();
// Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
sh0.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(message);

}
}


Try sh0.clearContents();

How big are the files

Your example is not a [mcve] in that it cannot reproduce the problem.


I believe the issue is that all of the SUMIF formulas in my original workbook are causing it to continuously recalculate as it copies in new data.

Chances are the issue is not related to the script but to the spreadsheet. Replace those formulas with something more efficient, perhaps a single query() formula.
To improve spreadsheet performance, see these optimization tips.
